# Angularjs 1.6 injector:nomod error message at Internet Explorer 10

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJs 1.6.4, when i open my website at internet explorer 10 it display the error message:

> [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/nomod?p0=mYApp

And a list of movies is not rendered.

At any other browser including Microsoft Edge, Chrome or Firefox the list is renderend as expected.

How can i track what causes the error, and fix for internet explorer 10 ?

My controller start using this syntax:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appMovies', [])

   .controller('Movies', function ($scope, $http, $window, $timeout, $filter, factoryMovies) {
```

Comment: I often see this error when specified dependencies in the controller have a trailing comma. most new browsers don't care, but IE will blow up.

Comment: how can it be done?

Comment: Look for some controller where there is a trailing comma -- `function ($scope, $http, $window, $timeout, $filter, factoryMovies,)` Remove the comma `function ($scope, $http, $window, $timeout, $filter, factoryMovies)`

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('appMovies', [])
.controller('Movies', 
   ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$timeout', '$filter', 'factoryMovies',
     function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout, $filter, factoryMovies) {
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Angular doc says "**This error occurs when you declare a dependency on a module that isn't defined anywhere or hasn't been loaded in the current browser context.**"

Now in your controller all dependencies except "**factoryMovies**" are angular's modules. So there is not question about them not pre-loaded. All $scope,$http, $timeout etc are pre-loaded with Angular.

Only culprit can be **factoryMovies** check this is already defined before you call this controller. There may be timing issue for IE. In IE somehow this controller getting called before you above mentioned module is loaded.

Comment: The weird thing here is that the error happens only into ie10 browser.